# Unknown cause of Missing \begin{document} error

Tags: preamble

I am working on a research paper and have recently been getting a "missing \begin{document}" error even though I've included it in what I believe to be the proper place.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym, mathtools,setspace, amsmath, indentfirst,upgreek,multirow,graphicx,verbatim,float,cases}
\usepackage{graphicx, underscore, subcaption, amsmath, wrapfig}

% nicer captions for figures and tables  
%\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}

% making larger margins
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}

% File path to images
\graphicspath{{path}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Custom and Renewed Commands %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% some additionally defined commands
\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Dt}[1]{\frac{\id #1}{\id t}}
\newcommand{\dt}[1]{\frac{\id #1}{\id t}}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure\ \ref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\frefs}[2]{Figures\ \ref{fig:#1}\ and\ \ref{fig:#2}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table\ \ref{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\trefs}[2]{Tables\ \ref{tab:#1}\ and\ \ref{tab:#2}}
\newcommand{\flab}[1]{\label{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{eqn.\ (\ref{eqn:#1})}
\newcommand{\erefs}[2]{eqns.\ (\ref{eqn:#1})--(\ref{eqn:#2}\mbox{)}}
\newcommand{\elab}[1]{\label{eqn:#1}}

\parskip 0.4cm


% style for reference citations in the text. Can be changed to other styles. Given in .bst file
\bibliographystyle{rspublicnat}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother 

\title{Mathematical Modeling of Virus Spread in Plants}
\author[1]{Auth1}
\author[2]{Auth2}
\affil[1]{Department of Mathematics, University of Tennessee, Knoxville, TN}
\affil[2]{Department of Microbiology, University of Tennessee, Knoxville, TN}
\date{}
\setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape \small}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
% ...
\end{document}
```

If you could help me identify the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `\author` doesn't take any optional argument in the `article` class. And you can't have more than one. You're using the template for another class.

Comment: Do you really need all those packages? Consider removing them all, seeing what breaks, and adding back only what you really need. It may cause brief pain, but can help understanding in the long run. If you really do them all, kindly disregard this message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using commands from the [`authblk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package, but you haven't loaded it. Adding

```
\usepackage{authblk}
```

anywhere in the preamble will fix the problem.

I'm not sure why the error *Missing `\begin{document}`* is thrown. LaTeX does not always have the best error messages, unfortunately.

Comment: Without authblk the command `\author[1]{Auth1}` sets the author list to be "[", and then "1]..." is left over and appears like document body text.

Comment: Ahh, thanks @DonaldArseneau!